# Entity Framework limit properties returned by Include

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I am using Include() to add related objects to query results. However, I don't want all the fields of the related table in the result set. I have managed to come up with the following solution, which works, but isn't there a better way to do this?

*Due to limitations on the client side, I cannot return a new type, with only the wanted fields. I need to return the correct type (Models.Message).*

```
private void LimitProperties(object entity, List<string> keepProps) {
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    PropertyInfo[] props = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (!keepProps.Contains(prop.Name))
        {
            prop.SetValue(entity, null);
        }
    }
}

public Models.Message GetMessageByID(int messageID) {
    List<string> _validProps = new List<string> { "ID", "Name", "Title" };

    Models.Message message = DbContext.Messages
        .Include(m => m.RefChannel)
        .Include(m => m.RefSender)
        .Include(m => m.RefRecipient)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == messageID);

    // limit the number of returned fields
    if (message != null)
    {
        LimitProperties(message.RefChannel, _validProps);
        LimitProperties(message.RefSender, _validProps);
        LimitProperties(message.RefRecipient, _validProps);
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: May I ask you why you don't want some properties to be set?

Comment: The Sender object, for example, contains user data which should not be transmitted to other users (who receive the message)

Comment: Really no other way? This is very hacky. You run the risk of saving modified entities. Can't you make the client side receive an `IMesssage`?

Comment: Have you tried to work with inherited classes you would make a class that have only the base properties and than a class that have the extended properties the ones that you don't always want to send. And than you make the extended class inerit from the base class. When you are making this quest simple cast the properties to the base class.

Comment: @Gabriel Monteiro Nepomuceno: That would probably work, but that means I have to inherit Message from a base class and also map RefChannel, RefSender and RefRecipient to base classes. I'm not sure that's better than my solution.

Comment: @mhu I've removed my answer, read over the question a little too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with adding `AsNoTracking()` to the query. So far I've not seen any negative side effects. I just need to make sure that Messages send (back) from the client have all the required properties set (but that's business as usual).

The complete code:

```
private void LimitProperties(object entity, List<string> keepProps) {
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    PropertyInfo[] props = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (!keepProps.Contains(prop.Name))
        {
            prop.SetValue(entity, null);
        }
    }
}

public Models.Message GetMessageByID(int messageID) {
    List<string> _validProps = new List<string> { "ID", "Name", "Title" };

    Models.Message message = DbContext.Messages
        .Include(m => m.RefChannel)
        .Include(m => m.RefSender)
        .Include(m => m.RefRecipient)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == messageID);

    // limit the number of returned fields
    if (message != null)
    {
        LimitProperties(message.RefChannel, _validProps);
        LimitProperties(message.RefSender, _validProps);
        LimitProperties(message.RefRecipient, _validProps);
    }

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having an object of type `RefSender` with some `null` values in this way is too risky. Because it is not clear that it's a **real null** or a **Not loaded null**.

As I understand your concern is about over richness of serialized object which will be used as a dto on the net. In this case you could have a `Custom Serializer` which you can ignore your fields to not to participate in serialization or even use some attributes like [NonSerialize] to ignore some fields.

Also as mentioned, in the situation you said, one solution is to create a base class `EntityBase` containing `Id`, `Name` and`Title`.

Comment: Yes, modifying the serialization was something I also considered, but I'm not sure how to add that to the WebAPI/MVC pipeline as an option (use the custom serializer in this case, and the default serializer for normal cases).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the risk. Will a call to SaveChanges() commit the null values of the included objects to the database?

Comment: @mhu Yep.. As you mentioned, that's the risk. In fact there is a null which you don't know is it a fake null or its made null by user at the interface. I'm not sure if there is a solution to customize serialization in the case. But you can have multiple inherited objects with different serializations. For example 'MessageBrief', 'Message', 'MessageFull'. All of these can have different ways of serialization policies.

Comment: Could I add `AsNoTracking()` to the query to get a non-tracked copy of the Message?

Comment: `AsNoTracking()` would return a detached object, but there's no promise that you wouldn't attach it to a `DbContext` again. As a matter of fact in the most of situations there's a detached dto which is loaded by client, modified and return back to the server, and then will be attached to `DbContext` to `SubmitChanges`